# webdriver.support.select - Select doesn't interact with the element

Tags: python, select, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

**Hello,
I have the following select:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<label class="ph_label pointer city">
<span class="l citylbl">City</span>
<select class="cities custom-dropdown" data-validation-error-msg="You  must select a city" required="" name="city" disabled="disabled" data-validation="required">
<option value="">City</option>
<option value="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
<option value="Beijing">Beijing</option>
<ul class="cities custom-dropdown" data-target-selector="select.cities" style="width: 293px;">
</label>
</div>
```

**I'm trying:**

```
mySelect = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("city"))
mySelect.select_by_value("Shanghai")
```

**When I see the test run, selenium goes through this element as if everything was OK, but in fact the city was not selected.
Any ideia?**

Comment: Any other elements with the `name="city"`?

Comment: only one element with this name!

Comment: did you try identifying the select with `other locators` instead of name? seems like you can have other elements with `name="city"`

Comment: yes, like xpath, css, etc..

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to the select in the code snippet is marked as disabled?

I have tried using Watir-webdriver, and if the `disabled="disabled"` attribute is there, I get the behavior you describe. As soon as I remove it, the value I want is selected.

Comment: Thanks for reply @chefsim. Worked with `dropdown_city = self.driver.find_element_by_name("city")
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("disabled");', dropdown_city)`